# Revision specifier for latest revision in trunk (or in a given branch)

Tags: svn

Some SVN commands (`update`, which is my main interest, but also `diff`, `log`...) accept a `-r` or `--revision` argument, and this can either be a literal revision number or some other [revision specifier](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html).

Is there a way to specify the latest revision in trunk?

I know how to specify a *target* that is the latest revision in trunk e.g. `https://svn/some_project/trunk@HEAD`. But this isn't a valid revision specifier and can't be used as an `-r` argument.

Answer (score 0):

For `svn log`: you can simply do like this to get the log message of the HEAD revision:

```
svn log https://svn/some_project/trunk -rHEAD
```

For `svn update`: it depends on what you want to do (see [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/fr/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html)), but in any case :

1. You need to have a working copy linked to trunk, so:

   - if you already have a working copy that is not linked to trunk, but should be: you can perform a switch with `svn switch https://svn/some_project/trunk path\to\working\copy`
   - otherwise you need to perform a check-out with `svn checkout -rHEAD https://svn/some_project/trunk`
2. Then later when needed, you can perform an update with `svn update -rHEAD path\to\working\copy`

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583072/conda-build-from-latest-revision-in-a-specific-svn-branch-or-trunk   It seems to revolve around `svn update`